# How can I add another condition to filter on in this elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an elasticsearch query that filters on business_process field. I would like to add another match clause so both fields have the specified data and I would like to add highlight on business_process field. How would I do that in elastic? Thank you in advance.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "business_process": "loading"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "client_cru_all"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ES documentation is your friend. The [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) is probably what you are looking for. Something like this should do what you want.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "business_process": "loading"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "another_field": "some text"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "missing": {
               "field": "client_cru_all"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As far as highlighting goes, I'd start [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html). If you can't get it to work, post what you tried in your question.

Comment: The ES documentation sucks!

Comment: Yeah, I don't disagree. Still, even a shitty friend has his uses. ;)

Comment: The highlight, is that an attribute at the top level inside query? Like where the "size": would be?

Comment: Top level *outside* the `"query"` block, like where [`"size"` and `"from"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) should be, yes.

Comment: and for this, `"highlight" : {
"fields" : {
"overview" : {}
}
}`. How do I ensure that the data in the overview field is surrounded with <strong></strong> tags instead of <em></em> tags? Shall I post another question about this so you can respond there?